# ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress

Tags: multisite, cookies

when you change domain or hosting or installation folder 
ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a plugin which I installed yesterday night.
In the next day I got this error.
SOLUTION : Deleted the plugin from wp-content/plugins and every thing was OK after that.

Answer (score -1):

after searching lot q & a . did not get answer.

but after researching i got the mistake , i.e. path return in wp_config.php
just write correct path i.e "/" .
login cookie issue solved  .

Answer (score -1):

Don't edit functions.php.

Why ?

1. Your WP site may stop responding
2. An WP update might ignore the code in functions.php

Use FREE Snippets plugin to modify your WP sensitive code:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

```
setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH ) setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

Just copy & paste code you need in a new snippet, and save.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What a great idea. So you allow to execute PHP code stored in DB, so if there is any vulnerability in WP allowing to put anything in DB, then attacker is able to execute any PHP code on the site. Superb ;) Really, it's one of the worst answers I've seen in here...

Comment: This solution works. For me it's ok access the backend, that was locked, and then remove this code.